# Исключение поля из Response.jsonPath()

Tags: java, json

В ответе приходит массив обьектов. Я делаю следующее:

```
List<MyClass> class = Response.jsonPath().getList("", MyClass.class);
```

В одном из обьектов есть поле (myField), которое не дессериализуется в MyClass.

Как его проигнорировать?